# Locality Sensitive Hashing to find nearest neighbours in Python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor, lsh

I am using [**this**](https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/distLSH/LocalitySensitiveHashing-1.0.1.html#LocalitySensitiveHashing) link to achieve the solution for my problem
I have a situation where I am using location sensitivity hashing to find the 3 nearest neighbours . My dataset has 22 columns both categorical and continuous and ab out 5000 rows. I am using the following code to run the LSH:

```
from LocalitySensitiveHashing import *
lsh = LocalitySensitiveHashing( 
               datafile = "df3_clean.csv",
               dim = 22,
               r = 5368,         
               b = 100,          
          )
lsh.get_data_from_csv()
lsh.initialize_hash_store()
lsh.hash_all_data()
similarity_neighborhoods = lsh.lsh_basic_for_nearest_neighbors()
lsh.write_clusters_to_file( merged_similarity_groups, "clusters.txt" )
```

I am getting this error : `ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize`

I have already encoded all of my dataset before passing into LSH and the data type for my data frame is float. What am I missing here?

How to print the result for top three neighbours? my first column in the dataframe is Cust_ID and I need to print the output as following:

```
CUST_ID     1st_neighbor.    2nd_neighbor      3rd_neighbor
0022        0012             1234              2233
0023        0022             1234              2231
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
lsh = LocalitySensitiveHashing( 
           datafile = "df3_clean.csv",
           dim = 22,
           r = 5368,         
           b = 100,          
      )
```

I Think the "df3_clean.csv" isn't reading the given file. Instead it's reading it as a string.
Try using pandas and then read the csv using pandas.
It'll solve this error.